# firebase cloud function snapshot undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

Im trying to write a function with firebase cloud function which will send an email as soon as a new message is added to my "contactMessages" realtime database. so i did this but here i got an undefined snapshot :

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
const gmailEmail = 
encodeURIComponent(functions.config().gmail.email);
const gmailPassword = 
encodeURIComponent(functions.config().gmail.password);
const mailTransport = nodemailer.createTransport(
`smtps://${gmailEmail}:${gmailPassword}@smtp.gmail.com`
 );

exports.sendContactMessage = functions.database
  .ref("/contactMessages/{pushKey}")
  .onWrite((change, context) => {
  // Only send email for new messages.
  if (snapshot.previous.val() || !snapshot.val().name) {
    return;
  }

  const val = snapshot.val();

  const mailOptions = {
    to: "test@example.com",
    subject: `Information Request from ${val.name}`,
    html: val.html
  };

  return mailTransport.sendMail(mailOptions).then(() => {
    return console.log("Mail sent to: test@example.com");
  });
});
```

Comment: `if (snapshot.previous.val() || !snapshot.val().name) {` snapshot is undefined here..

Comment: yes but i don't know what i should do instead ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
   exports.sendContactMessage = functions.database
  .ref("/contactMessages/{pushKey}")
  .onWrite((change, context) => {
  // Only send email for new messages.
  if (snapshot.previous.val() || !snapshot.val().name) {
    return;
  }
```

into this:

```
exports.sendContactMessage = functions.database
  .ref("/contactMessages/{pushKey}")
  .onWrite((change, context) => {
  // Only send email for new messages.
  if (change.before.val() || !change.after.val().name) {
    return;
  }
```

From the docs:

> For `onWrite` and `onUpdate` events, the `change` parameter has `before` and `after` fields. Each of these is a `DataSnapshot` with the same methods available in [`admin.database.DataSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.DataSnapshot).